# How to prove the first k eigenvalue of hermitian matrix [P11 P12 P12* P22] is bigger than eigenvalue of P11

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the following but I have no clue where to start.

Let $P = P^* = \begin{pmatrix}P_{11} &P_{12} \\ P_{12}^* &P_{22}\end{pmatrix}$.  Dimension of $P_{11}$ is $K \times K$. Show $\lambda_i(P) \geq
\lambda_i(P_{11})$ for any $1\leq i\leq k$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The eigenvalues of a matrix are not naturally ordered. You need to specify which eigenvalue is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue. In your case, the statement is true when $\lambda_i$ is decreasing (i.e $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \cdots$ ). This is known as [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) which can be proved using min-max principle.

Answer (score 1):

It is a consequence of Cauchy interlacing property extended to hermitian matrices.

(https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254975415_Cauchy's_Interlace_Theorem_for_Eigenvalues_of_Hermitian_Matrices)

Use this property by considering the transition from upper left block $P_{11}$ to the whole matrix $P$ by successive "borderings", i.e. intermediate matrices obtained by adding a column on the right and a row at the bottom.